# How can I have multiple servers and IPs if I only have 1 ip with gigabit connection?

Tags: routing, ip, bgp, isp, route-server

I have 1 gigabit connection with static public IP address...

Without depending on my local ISPs colaboration, is it possible to buy IPs from an online service and route each individual IP to my local servers trough my single gigabit connection ?
Maybe get the IPs from a provider that offers something like "transit" dedicated servers, is that what these "transit servers" are used for ?

Basically what I want to achieve is to have multiple available IPs that can be used with my local servers just like I would rent servers from a hosting provider.

The problem is I am not familiar at all with relevant protocols or services that are available.

As a general ideea I am thinking if I pay for a dedicated server in some data center, it should be possible to get multiple IPs routed to that server and that server keeping a dedicated connection to my home single static IP, no ?

What would I need for something like that ?
I think normally this is done by BGP and I need connections from 2 ISPs, but I am looking for alternatives. My current ISP doesn't offer much help with this method, and I don't have 2 ISPs at this location.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I have multiple servers and IPs if I only have 1 ip with gigabit connection?

Up to the network layer (L3), you can't. You can employ transport layer (L4) ports, ie. use a destination NAT router with multiple port forwarding mappings to different servers (e.g. port 80 goes to server1, port 81 to server2, etc.)

Another alternative is a reverse proxy for HTTP/S on the application layer (L7), off topic here.

> is it possible to buy IPs from an online service and route each individual IP to my local servers trough my single gigabit connection ?

Only when your ISP agrees to advertise those IP addresses (/24 subnet or larger) to their BGP peers and to forward them to you. Without their collaboration and without tunneling you can't.

Tunneling means that the IPs are routed elsewhere and you've created a tunnel connection to that location. You can then use that tunnel to route those IPs to your actual location. Possibly, this is what 'transit server' means, there's no general definition.

Comment: The only additional comment I would add is that if your ISP does not offer the option for more paid IP addresses, they obviously do not want you hosting services/servers on your connection and you may face additional issues with port blocking, usage restrictions and acceptable use policies. These issues and more add up to why most people simply use a hosting provider or cloud hosting service for this kind of need.

Comment: They offer some additional IPs and allow servers/services, but they are unprofessional and more "sensitive" regarding complaints than a normal web hosting company, because most of their clients do not host serververs/services. They disable the connection on any kind of complaint without understanding the situation. It's better to have IPs from other ISPs or have my own.

Comment: I don't know much about IP protocols but looking at how many protocols exist in a Mikrotik router for example, it must be something to route all traffic from multiple IPs from other ISP, to my local IP and mark/label that traffic somehow in order to direct it to each server. Maybe even by `source ip` kind of rules or something.

Comment: That something is a tunnel of some kind. You 'mark' it by encapsulating the rerouted traffic in another IP packet or transport-layer datagram.